# error in switch statement in java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

this is the code-

```
     import java.util.Scanner;
    public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter a four digit number");
    int number=kb.nextInt();
    int digit2=number;

    switch (digit1)
    {
        case 1: System.out.println("One");break;
        case 2: System.out.println("Two");break;
        case 3: System.out.println("Three");break;
        case 4: System.out.println("Four");break;
        case 5: System.out.println("Five");break;
        case 6: System.out.println("Six");break;
        case 7: System.out.println("Seven");break;
        case 8: System.out.println("Eight");break;
        case 9: System.out.println("Nine");break;
        case 0: System.out.println("Zero");break;
        default: System.out.println("");break;
    }
    switch (digit2)
        {
            case 1: System.out.println("One");break;
        case 2: System.out.println("Two");break;
        case 3: System.out.println("Three");break;
        case 4: System.out.println("Four");break;
        case 5: System.out.println("Five");break;
        case 6: System.out.println("Six");break;
        case 7: System.out.println("Seven");break;
        case 8: System.out.println("Eight");break;
        case 9: System.out.println("Nine");break;
        case 0: System.out.println("Zero");break;
        default: System.out.println("");break;
        }
     }
}
```

And this error is coming

```
2 errors                                                                                                                                                     
sh-4.3$ javac HelloWorld.java                                                                                                                                
HelloWorld.java:10: error: cannot find symbol                                                                                                                
    switch (digit1)                                                                                                                                          
            ^                                                                                                                                                
  symbol:   variable digit1                                                                                                                                  
  location: class HelloWorld                                                                                                                                 
HelloWorld.java:10: error: illegal start of type                                                                                                             
    switch (digit1)                                                                                                                                          
           ^                                                                                                                                                 
2 errors
```

pls help me

Comment: where is digit1 declared?

Comment: There is no digit1 variable in your program :) .

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a variable named `digit1`.

Here's some rough code to do what you want:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a four digit number");

      String numStr = kb.next();

      int number = 0;
      try {
         number = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Input was not a number!");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      if (number < 1000) {
         System.out.println("Number must be at least four digits!");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      for (int digitNdx = 0; digitNdx < 4; digitNdx++) {
         switch (numStr.charAt(digitNdx)) {
            case '1':
               System.out.println("One");
               break;
            case '2':
               System.out.println("Two");
               break;
            case '3':
               System.out.println("Three");
               break;
            case '4':
               System.out.println("Four");
               break;
            case '5':
               System.out.println("Five");
               break;
            case '6':
               System.out.println("Six");
               break;
            case '7':
               System.out.println("Seven");
               break;
            case '8':
               System.out.println("Eight");
               break;
            case '9':
               System.out.println("Nine");
               break;
            case '0':
               System.out.println("Zero");
               break;
            default:
               System.out.println("");
               break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework-writing service.  Please don't give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: @JoeC alright, I'll only post information specifically relating to their issue next time.  Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter a four digit number");
int number = kb.nextInt();
int digit2 = number;

switch (digit1) {
```

---

Error occur due to

> **here is no any variable assigned for `digit1`**

---

Example

```
int digit1 = 5;
int digit2 = number;
```